# Comparing two lists and inserting Nulls where necessary

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have two lists a master list and a subset of that list, I want to compare the master to the subset and then insert nulls where the subset is missing in python.

There is a need for the value to be separated after a pipe but it is not important when comparing the two lists.

Master list

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

Subset

```
["A|1" , "D|41", "F|34", "F|54"]
```

Desired outcome

```
["A|1","NULL","NULL","D|41","NULL","F|34", "F|54"]
```

Any help welcomed.

Comment: @VigneshKalai Yes it is a character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create an extra list you could use this method but the top voted answer would be faster

**Code:**

```
inp_check=["A|1" , "D|41", "F|34"]
inp_master=["A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
print [next((value2 for value2 in inp_check if value in value2 ) ,"null") for value in inp_master]
```

**Output:**

```
['A|1', 'null', 'null', 'D|41', 'null', 'F|34']
```

**Edit:**

**Code1:**

```
inp_check=["A|1" , "D|41", "F|34", 'F|56']
inp_master=["A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
output=[]
for value in inp_master:
    check=0
    for check_value in inp_check:
        if value in check_value:
            check=1
            output.append(check_value)
    if check ==0:
        output.append("NULL")
print output
```

**Output:**

```
['A|1', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'D|41', 'NULL', 'F|34', 'F|56']
```

Comment: inp_check doesn't exist I tried running the code after changing that and it didnt insert any nulls

Comment: `inp_check=["A|1" , "D|41", "F|34", 'F|56']
inp_master=["A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
print [next((value2 for value2 in inp_check if value in value2 ) ,"null") for value in inp_master]`  In this example though if I add another F value. it is not picked up in the final list.. Do you know any remedy?

Comment: `inp_check=["A|1" , "D|41", "F|34", 'F|56']
inp_master=["A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
print [next((value2 for value2 in inp_check if value in value2 ) ,"null") for value in inp_master]`     

output

  `C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/C2043027/PycharmProjects/PIM/testiter.py
['A|1', 'null', 'null', 'D|41', 'null', 'F|34']`

missing F value of 56.

Comment: @BasicHorizon what is the expected output in that case

Comment: `['A|1', 'null', 'null', 'D|41', 'null', 'F|34', 'F|56']`

Do you think this is possible

Answer (score 2):

Let's say:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
list2 = ['A|1' , 'D|41', 'F|34']
```

Create the list to compare with

```
comp_list2 = [ x.split('|')[0] for x in list2 ]
```

select common values

```
result = [ list2[comp_list2.index(x)] if x in comp_list2 else "NULL" for x in list1 ] # Better Replace "NULL" with None

print result

['A|1', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'D|41', 'NULL', 'F|34']
```

Voilà

Comment: `comp_list2 = [ x[0] for x in list2 ]`

Comment: @saulspatz it would not work when x is `something like "AB"` we have to think more then the sample given

Comment: @YOBA Really good answer and it did work but could you just explain this for me
`result = [ list2[comp_list2.index(x)] if x in comp_list2 else "NULL" for x in list1 ]`

Comment: @Vigneshi Kalaia Point taken.

Comment: @BasicHorizon we are comparing list1 with comp_list2, but we need for the output, the values of list2, so comp_list2.index(x) is looking for x in comp_list2 and providing its index to list2, if it doesn't find it "NULL" is the value appended to the list.

Comment: @VigneshKalai exactly, this is why I used split.

Comment: @YOBA there is a problem if there subset has two values of the same they wont be inserted I don't think.. only one of them will go in.

Comment: @BasicHorizon Well sure, this is another issue, you need to make this precision on the question, and also if the order is important.

Comment: @YOBA I don't think it is possible to do what I am asking and preserve the order.. So I guess I may have to let the ordering go and try and sort it back at a later point but picking up the same value twice is necessary

Comment: @YOBA I have edited the original question to include a second index containing the same value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89300/discussion-between-basichorizon-and-yoba).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method which actually performs what is asked in the question and **inserts** the values into the original list rather than creating a new list.

```
master = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
sub = ["A|1" , "D|41", "F|34"]

for i, elem in enumerate(master):
     try:
         next_ = sub[i]
     except IndexError:
         next_ = ''
     if not next_.startswith(elem):
         sub.insert(i, 'Null')
```

Comment: Only problem with this answer is that it inserts all the nulls at the beginning. not in order I believe

Comment: No it will insert the `'Null'` at position `i` in the list

Comment: You're right it does but for some reason when I do it with my actual data not sample data all the nulls go to the beginning.

Comment: @BasicHorizon you are right, the data will need to be sorted beforehand, I will update the answer in a bit.